# Pillow equivalent of the following openCV code

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, python-imaging-library

I am trying to convert the following code module written in openCV to pillow but I am unable to figure out to do it?
j is an rgb image

```
img = cv2.imread(j,1)
b,g,r = cv2.split(img)
green = 2*g-r-b
```

Here ,I am reading an coloured image and then splitting into channels and then performing a transformation on the green channel and then further using the green channel for further operation but I am unable to figure the pillow equivalent of the above code.
I tried this question [Python PIL image split to RGB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51325224/python-pil-image-split-to-rgbv) but I was not able to get the result for `2*g-r-b`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python PIL image split to RGB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51325224/python-pil-image-split-to-rgb)

Comment: I have tried the above mentioned question but was unable to perform the operation `2*g-r-b` on it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that using PIL and Numpy like this - I tend to go into Numpy as it is faster and more flexible:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

# Open input image and ensure it is RGB
im = Image.open('start.png').convert('RGB')

# Make into Numpy array
imnp = np.array(im)

# Split into 3 constituent bands
r = imnp[:, :, 0]
g = imnp[:, :, 1]
b = imnp[:, :, 2]

# Process
g = 2*g - r - b

# Recombine to single image and save
merged = np.dstack((r, g, b))
Image.fromarray(merged).save('result.png')
```

---

Or you can be less explicit about splitting and do it in-place on the whole image:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

# Open input image and ensure it is RGB
im = Image.open('start.png').convert('RGB')

# Make into Numpy array
imnp = np.array(im)

# Process
imnp[:,:,1] = 2*imnp[:,:,1] - imnp[:,:,0] - imnp[:,:,2]

# Save
Image.fromarray(imnp).save('result2.png')
```

**Keywords**: Python, Numpy, PIL, Pillow, color matrix, colour matrix, transform, multiply channel, scale channel, separate, separately, individual channels, bands, components, individually, image, image processing.

Comment: Yes , it solved my issue but is there any way by which I don't have to save the image every time and can use the specific color channel bands for further processing . Because in openCV , I can use the separate band (suppose green in this case) and can perform operations on it without saving anything

Comment: Of course. You don't have to save anything. I only showed how to recombine the channels as a courtesy since I split them up and guessed you might want to recombine them but you don't have to. Note also that the Numpy arrays I use (`imnp`, `r`, `g` and `b`) are exactly the same, and completely interchangeable with your OpenCV `img`, `b`, `g` and `r`. You can use my arrays with your OpenCV code or your OpenCV arrays with my Numpy/PiIL code!

Comment: Yes, I got it. Thanks a lot.